# Calculate percentage in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there any method available to calculate percentage in rails or ruby ??

EDIT:

I am looking for a function like ..

`100000.percent(10)` will return me `10000`.

`100000` is value ..(value is `BigDecimal`)
`10 %` ..

`result = 100000 * 10 / 100`

`result = 10000` ..

Comment: What do you mean, "calculate percentage"? You can use multiplication and division like any other language: * /

Comment: Is there any method available for this ??

Comment: There is no builtin method, because the division operator is usually used for this.  Why do you need a method over normal division?  If you *must* have a method, write one that wraps a simple division operator (see several examples below).

Comment: it'd help if you were more clear with your question.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You mean like this `percentage = a/b*100`?

**Update** based on your new description:

```
class Numeric
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
  end
end

# Note: the brackets () around number are optional
p (1).percent_of(10)    # => 10.0  (%)
p (200).percent_of(100) # => 200.0 (%)
p (0.5).percent_of(20)  # => 2.5   (%)

pizza_slices = 5
eaten = 3
p eaten.percent_of(pizza_slices) # => 60.0 (%)
```

Based on Mladen's code.

Comment: @randomguy But is there any method available for this ??

Comment: you can use the `:/` method: `a.to_f.send(:/, b).send(:*,100)` furthermore, this question makes me feel `:/`

Comment: Is it work if my value is in BigDecimal ??

Comment: @randomguy: Hey, thanks for the credits, it's really nice to have an effort of such magnitude recognized! :o)

Comment: @Mladen: Thanks for the sarcasm. I need it, House is still on break. :<

Comment: I like it more to say 50.percent_of(200) = 100. So for my case `n.to_f * self.to_f / 100.0` works.

Comment: @fabro I agree, and that's consistent with the percentage gem. It uses `as_percentage_of` instead of `percent_of`, which I think is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method. Here it is:

```
class Numeric
  def percents
    self * 100
  end
end

0.56.percents
=> 56.0
```

Comment: i want a method something like .. 100000.percent(10) will return me 10000.

Comment: @krunal Then you want `100000 * .1`. You don't want a method.

Comment: @Mladen my favourite answer ever on SO :)

Comment: @rmcsharry make my day I was in search of ruby syntax sugar and this one is my best

Comment: @RomanKlevtcov 5 years after my comment, and yes, it's still my favourite answer ever...but it's not my answer...so don't thank me, thanks Mladen Jablanovic!